# Looping a switch statement

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I have a "menu" in a console app. Now when I have finished picking an item out of the menu and doing what that menu item require I want to loop and show the menu again so that the user can choose a diffenrent menu item. I have an exit on the menu and I only want to use that to exit. I have tried a while loop but this doesnt work. It closes the app after a menu item has been chosen and the chosen items code has run. What am I doing wrong?

```
static void Main()
    {   
        int input = 0;
        while (true)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("MENU");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number that you want to do:");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Do thing A");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Do thing B");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Do thing C");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Do thing D");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Do thing E");
            Console.WriteLine("6. Do thing F");
            Console.WriteLine("7. Exit");

            int menuchoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (menuchoice)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Thing A has been done"); 
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Thing B has been done");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Thing C has been done");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Thing D has been done");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.WriteLine("Thing E has been done");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Console.WriteLine("Thing F has been done");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Environment.Exit; //edit
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, invalid selection");
                    break;
            }

            input++;
            if (input < 30)
                continue;
            else
                break;
        }           
    }
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I am aware that that "Console.Exit" would not work. I did just put it like that to illastrate that the console must exit there. My problem is that I need to loop the whole menu every time after a option have been chosen and the chosen option code has run. I only want to use the exit to exit. But at this point the menu does not loop, the console closes after just 1 option have been chosen and that options code has run.

EDIT: What happens when you start your program and you press 1 followed by Return? This is the real problem, the menu doesnt seem to be looping. After I start my program and press 1 followed by return the code in case 1 runs perfectly but then the console just closes. If I start the console again and press 2 this time the code in case 2 also runs perfectly but then the console closes again. I have tested all my cases like this and all of them runs perfectly.

Comment: What's the problem? (Replace Console.Exit by Environment.Exit())

Comment: Regarding your edit: For me your sample loops as I would expect it. What happens when you start your program (`Console.Exit` replaced by `Environment.Exit`) and you press 1 followed by Return? I suspect that the sample you posted is somewhat different from the code you are running (obviously it is, because the sample above does not compile).

Comment: I am aware that that "Console.Exit" would not work. I did just put it like that to illastrate that the console must exit there. I have tried Environment.Exit(), but doesnt seem to work either.

Comment: Can you please post the *exact* compilable code that is not working? It seems your problem is within a small detail.

Comment: This code (as posted) should repeat the while loop thirty times. You can simply add a `return` statement in case 7, for the sake of this test. But if your program **always ends, after every single command** (if I got it right), then you are not posting your actual code here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep it simple: the loop stays in the loop until 7 is pressed

```
  int menuchoice  = 0;  
        while (menuchoice != 7)  
        {  

            Console.WriteLine("MENU");  
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number that you want to do:");  
            Console.WriteLine("1. Do thing A");  
            Console.WriteLine("2. Do thing B");  
            Console.WriteLine("3. Do thing C");  
            Console.WriteLine("4. Do thing D");  
            Console.WriteLine("5. Do thing E");  
            Console.WriteLine("6. Do thing F");  
            Console.WriteLine("7. Exit");  

            menuchoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  

            switch (menuchoice)  
            {  
                case 1:  
                    Console.WriteLine("Thing A has been done");   
                    break;  
                case 2:  
                    Console.WriteLine("Thing B has been done");  
                    break;  
                case 3:  
                    Console.WriteLine("Thing C has been done");  
                    break;  
                case 4:  
                    Console.WriteLine("Thing D has been done");  
                    break;  
                case 5:  
                    Console.WriteLine("Thing E has been done");  
                    break;  
                case 6:  
                    Console.WriteLine("Thing F has been done");  
                    break;  
                case 7:  
                    break;  //edit
                default:  
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, invalid selection");  
                    break;  
            }
```

Comment: Your sample doesn't compile. You would have to replace `Console.Exit` (which is the actual problem with the sample).

Comment: The menu does not loop, the console closes after just 1 option have been chosen and that options code has run. Can't the problem be with the break statement after each case?

Comment: @CSharpSuzie: No, the `break` statement should be fine. `break` always leaves the innermost enclosing loop or switch statement as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, but what if I want to exit when either 7 or 8 is entered?
Seems like While() doesn't take 2 arguments: While (menuchoice != 7 || menuchoice != 8) won't work! Please help!

Answer (score 4):

Replace `Console.Exit;` with `input = 30;` or just use `return;`

Be aware the the line `int menuchoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` produces an error if the user enters a character. You might use `int.TryParse`...

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me **IF** I remove that `Console.Exit`. What is that? It doesn't seem to be in the documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console_members.aspx

As @madgnome says in the comment, you should replace that with `Environment.Exit()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your code sample does not compile because there is no `Console.Exit`.

Simply replace `Console.Exit; break;` with a `return;` statement and your sample should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way is to do the following. use input counter as flag to exit while loop.

```
 case 7:
   input =30;
 break;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine on my machine, but stops after 30 commands of course as your logic dictates.

The `Console.Exit` gives a copilation error on my machine. I have never used `Console.Exit` before.

Can't you just repalce it with `input = 30;` to break your loop?