# Looping Switch Statements

Tags: c#, loops, switch-statement

I'm trying to determine the best way to get the following code to iterate until the user enters a valid number(1-6). As long as the user inputs a number that is greater than 6, the program should continue to prompt the user for a valid number.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          string favoriteBand;

        Console.WriteLine("What is your favorite rock band?");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("1.) Journey");
        Console.WriteLine("2.) Boston");
        Console.WriteLine("3.) Styx");
        Console.WriteLine("4.) Kansas");
        Console.WriteLine("5.) Foreigner");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 6 to exit the program.");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        favoriteBand = (Console.ReadLine());

        switch (favoriteBand)
        {
            case "1": Console.WriteLine("Don't Stop Believin'!"); break;            
            case "2": Console.WriteLine("More Than a Feeling!"); break;
            case "3": Console.WriteLine("Come Sail Away!"); break;
            case "4": Console.WriteLine("Dust in the Wind!"); break;
            case "5": Console.WriteLine("Hot Blooded!"); break;
            case "6": return;
            default: Console.WriteLine("Error, invalid choice. Please choose a valid number."); break;

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

How can I get this program to continue prompting for a valid number using a loop?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looping a switch statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767449/looping-a-switch-statement)

Comment: Also if I use the int data type for my favoriteBand variable, it won't allow me to use switch statements.

Comment: @user3311305 sure, just change `"1"` to `1`, etc.

Comment: `6` is valid or not ?

Comment: @Selman22 It's valid input that informs the program that it should exit.

Comment: Thank you. Changing the data type to int allowed me to use a do...while(favoriteBand > 6); that was all that I needed. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here we can remove the switch
(not really needed for a simple switch with only 6 cases)

```
bool isValid = true;

Dictionary<string, Action> command = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
command.Add("1", () => {Console.WriteLine("Don't Stop Believin'!");isValid = false;});
command.Add("2", () => {Console.WriteLine("More Than a Feeling!");isValid = false;});
command.Add("3", () => {Console.WriteLine("Come Sail Away!");isValid = false;});
command.Add("4", () => {Console.WriteLine("Dust in the Wind!");isValid = false;});
command.Add("5", () => {Console.WriteLine("Hot Blooded!");isValid = false;});
command.Add("6", () => isValid = false);

while(isValid)
{
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    if(command.Keys.Contains(line)) 
        command[line].Invoke();
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Choose from 1 to 6");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `bool` variable with `while`

```
  bool control = true;
  while(control)
  {
    favoriteBand = (Console.ReadLine());
    switch (favoriteBand)
    {
        case "1": Console.WriteLine("Don't Stop Believin'!"); control = false;break;            
        case "2": Console.WriteLine("More Than a Feeling!");control = false; break;
        case "3": Console.WriteLine("Come Sail Away!"); control = false;break;
        case "4": Console.WriteLine("Dust in the Wind!"); control = false;break;
        case "5": Console.WriteLine("Hot Blooded!"); control = false;break;
        case "6": control = false; break;
        default: Console.WriteLine("Error, invalid choice. Please choose a valid number.");  break;

    }    
  }
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked for the purposed of asking for valid input, but once I re-enter the valid input I want the program to stop iterating.