# I want a menu to repeat after invalid option?

Tags: java

Ok I know this must be simpler than I am making it out to be, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have menu. the user selects a number which calls a certain method.

I want the menu to repeat if they do not select a valid option. and then I want to give them the option to select another option or end the program.

Can anyone help me out?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TestStringManip {
        //=================MAIN===============
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        String input = in.nextLine();

        StringManipulation newString = new StringManipulation(input);

        String menu = "\n Please select an option to perform"
                + "\n1 (1) Get all uppercase letters."
                + "\n2 (2) Get every second letter."
                + "\n3 (3) Replace vowels with _ "
                + "\n4 (4) Get a count of all vowels."
                + "\n5 (5) Get position of all vowels.";
        System.out.println(menu);
        int option = in.nextInt();


        do
        {
            if (option == 1)
            {
                newString.getUpperCase(input);
            }

            else if (option == 2)
            {
                newString.getEverySecond(input);
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error must select 1-5");
                System.out.println(menu);
                option = in.nextInt();
            }
        }while (option < 1 || option > 5);
    }

}
```

I have updated my code to try some of the suggested answers. It works for the first two options but that is it. I am also trying to get it to repeat after each option is chosen unless 0 is chosen which should end the program. Here is my updated code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TestStringManip {
        //=================MAIN===============
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        String input = in.nextLine();

        StringManipulation newString = new StringManipulation(input);

        String menu = "\n Please select an option to perform"
                + "\n1 (1) Get all uppercase letters."
                + "\n2 (2) Get every second letter."
                + "\n3 (3) Replace vowels with _ "
                + "\n4 (4) Get a count of all vowels."
                + "\n5 (5) Get position of all vowels."
                + "\n0 (0) Exit Program";
        System.out.println(menu);
        int option = in.nextInt();

        int i = 0;
        do
        {   
            if (option == 1)
            {
                newString.getUpperCase(input);
                i = 1;
            }

            else if (option == 2)
            {
                newString.getEverySecond(input);
                i = 1;
            }

            else if (option == 3)
            {
                newString.replaceVowels(input);
                i = 1;
            }

            else if (option == 4)
            {
                newString.getNumberOfVowels(input);
                i = 1;
            }

            else if (option == 5)
            {
                newString.getVowelPosition(input);
                i = 1;
            }

            else if (option == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error must select 0-5");
                System.out.println("Enter your option: ");
                option = in.nextInt();
            }
        }while (i == 0);

    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looping a switch statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767449/looping-a-switch-statement)

Comment: You need to modify your logic. You only want to enter choice when an invalid number is entered. Can you please tell me what will happen if user enters a valid option? As you are putting it inside a loop, so it will become an infinite loop. To avoid this thing, you need to ask for user's choice on each iteration, so it does not enter into an infinite loop. Check My Answer.

Comment: You MUST ask for another option even if user enters the valid option, only then loop will work fine, otherwise it will be an infinite loop once user enters a valid option. Try to run the code, you will come to know, what I am trying to say.

Comment: Got it I'll work on that. I'm pretty new here and still figuring things out. so far for this question I do not have an answer that seems to work.

Comment: @user3769297 check my answer, tell me if that's what you were looking for, it's not really clear for me, so I did my best with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want to do, repeat the whole menu unless user press `0`, then exit.

I made it with `switch` instead of `if-else`. But you can change that piece of code. Try it and tell me if this is what you were looking for.

***This one validates the input BEFORE processing it on switch***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int option;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            do {
                String menu = "\n Please select an option to perform"
                                + "\n1 (1) Get all uppercase letters."
                                + "\n2 (2) Get every second letter."
                                + "\n3 (3) Replace vowels with _ "
                                + "\n4 (4) Get a count of all vowels."
                                + "\n5 (5) Get position of all vowels."
                                + "\n0 (0) Exit Program";
                System.out.println(menu);
                option = in.nextInt();
            } while(option < 0 || option > 5); // This will make the menu repeat if option is higher than 6 or lowen than 0.

            switch(option) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Option 1");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Option 2");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Option 3");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Option 4");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Option 5");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Hasta la vista Baby");
                    break; //I always use this break, even when not needed.
            }
        } while (option != 0);
    }
}
```

## **EDIT**

As [GPRathour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623023/i-want-a-menu-to-repeat-after-invalid-option/24623768#comment38164776_24623768) pointed out, you can do it with a simple `do-while` loop, so it would look like this:

***This one validates the input AFTER processing it on switch***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int option;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            String menu = "\n Please select an option to perform"
            + "\n1 (1) Get all uppercase letters."
            + "\n2 (2) Get every second letter."
            + "\n3 (3) Replace vowels with _ "
            + "\n4 (4) Get a count of all vowels."
            + "\n5 (5) Get position of all vowels."
            + "\n0 (0) Exit Program";
            System.out.println(menu);
            option = in.nextInt();
            switch(option) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Hasta la vista Baby");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Option 1");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Option 2");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Option 3");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Option 4");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Option 5");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Wrong option");
                    break; //I always use this break, even when not needed.
            }
        } while (option != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added my constructor before the do loops. and I added the method calls to each class and I get an error when I run it.

Comment: I don't know I keep trying different things. Here is what I have now, but I don't have it exactly like you do now.C:\Users\Timothy\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:48:

Comment: I got this to work. I'm not sure what I did wrong before, but I just cleared everything and started from scratch. Thanks

Comment: -1 I just wonder what is the need of nested loops in this scenerio, it is a simple logic and can be achieved in a simpler way using only one loop. Why to make it this complex?

Comment: @GPRathour validation purposes, that's why I use nested loops, it validates user input, if user doesn't writes a number between 0 and 5, then he can't continue, I know it can be achieved by 1 loop but as I mentioned I didn't fully understood what OP was asking, so I added code for both validations. Once I'm on a PC I'll edit it with another example

Comment: @GPRathour would you like to check the edit? I posted new code with a simple loop

Answer (score 1):

Try a switch statement. Replace your if statement with this block of code.

```
do{
    switch(option){
        case 0:
             //Exit loop
             break;
        case 1:
             newString.getUpperCase(input);
             break;
        case 2:
             newString.getEverySecond(input);
             break;
        case 3:
             // Method number 3;
        . . .

        default:
            System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 5");
            break;
    }
} while(option !=0)
```

**EDIT**
If you want to know more about switch statements, check out this [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Re-edit:And yeah, you'll have to check for int input rather than a string like Ricky stated

Comment: This doesn't answer his question, although his question is pretty unclear at this point. He asked about looping.

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
  public class TestStringManip {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String menu = "\n Please select an option to perform"
            + "\n1 (1) for option one enter 1."
            + "\n2 (2) for option two enter 2."
            + "\n0 (0) Exit Program";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option = ReadAndMenu(menu,in);

    int i = 0;
    do {
        if (option == 1) {
            System.out.println("option one");
            option = ReadAndMenu(menu,in);
        } else if (option == 2) {
            System.out.println("option two");
            option = ReadAndMenu(menu,in);
        } else if (option == 0){
            System.out.println("exit");
            i= 1; 
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 2");
            option = ReadAndMenu(menu,in);

        }
    } while (i == 0);

}

 private static int ReadAndMenu(String menu, Scanner in){
        System.out.println(menu);
        System.out.print("Enter your option: ");
        return in.nextInt();
    }
```

}

output:

```
Please select an option to perform
1 (1) for option one enter 1.
2 (2) for option two enter 2.
0 (0) Exit Program
Enter your option: 1
option one

 Please select an option to perform
1 (1) for option one enter 1.
2 (2) for option two enter 2.
0 (0) Exit Program
Enter your option: 2
option two

 Please select an option to perform
1 (1) for option one enter 1.
2 (2) for option two enter 2.
0 (0) Exit Program
Enter your option: 5
Please enter a number between 1 and 2

 Please select an option to perform
1 (1) for option one enter 1.
2 (2) for option two enter 2.
0 (0) Exit Program
Enter your option: 0
```

Comment: So I tried this and at first it seemed to work, It works for the first two options but the last ones do not work. for some reason. I have updated my code. above. I also added an option to exit.

Comment: you have to define other else if to support other numbers did u do it? I just gave u this as a blue print so you can tailor it for ur need. :)

Comment: I check your question now, and I think I gave you enough info to satisfy your need

Comment: -1 Your code calls same method again and again. There is no need to create a separate method for this. You can do it in a simpler way as I suggested in my answer. And please have a look at my edit too.

Comment: I got the answer below to work, but I think there is something that I messed up with your version because it worked for the first two. but I was trying so many different things I had to just start from scratch because I think I just had something random in there. thanks for the help.

Comment: u r welcome happy u found answer :) but I don't understand what u mean but it is k good luck :)

Comment: @KickButtowski Kid, You should not take it personal when someone downvotes your answer. And you should not take revenge of it. You are earning reputation on this site only, you are not earning money and you cannot utilize this reputation any where else. So don't be obsessed with it. I down voted because your approach in your logic is not good enough. You can make it better.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a check to Scanner.hasNextInt() to make sure that the user is actually typing in an int. Because right now, if someone were to type "Hello", it would break your program. I fixed the code, and hopefully the loop.

Here's an example, using a modified version of your code: (sorry for the wonky indentation - yours is weird, and I haven't fixed it yet. Will edit with a fix)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestStringManip {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        String input = in.nextLine();

        StringManipulation newString = new StringManipulation(input);

        String menu = "\n Please select an option to perform"
                + "\n1 (1) Get all uppercase letters."
                + "\n2 (2) Get every second letter."
                + "\n3 (3) Replace vowels with _ "
                + "\n4 (4) Get a count of all vowels."
                + "\n5 (5) Get position of all vowels.";
        System.out.println(menu);

        int option = getIntInput(in);

        do{
            if (option == 1)
            {
                newString.getUpperCase(input);
            }

            else if (option == 2)
            {
                newString.getEverySecond(input);
            }

            else if (option == 0){
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            else
            {
                option = getIntInput(in);
            }

          }while(option != 0);
    }

  //this function will keep prompting until the user inputs a valid option
  int getIntInput(Scanner in){
     while(!in.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid option (# between 1 and 5)");
     }

     return in.nextInt();
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you want your logic to work I believe there should be an option to exit too. So how about trying something like the following,

```
do{
      String menu = "\n Please select an option to perform"
        + "\n1 (1) Get all uppercase letters."
        + "\n2 (2) Get every second letter."
        + "\n3 (3) Replace vowels with _ "
        + "\n4 (4) Get a count of all vowels."
        + "\n5 (5) Get position of all vowels."
        + "\n0 (0) To Exit.";
     System.out.println(menu);
     int option = in.nextInt();


    if (option == 1){
        newString.getUpperCase(input);
    }

    else if (option == 2){
        newString.getEverySecond(input);
    }
    ...
    ...
    else if(option == 0){
        break;
    }else{
        System.out.println("\n\nWrong Choice\n\n");
    }

}while(option != 0);
```

**EDIT**

As Kick Buttowski was having so many doubts. I created two simple examples, just run them on your own and see the output, as I don't have enough time to upload screenshots of output of both of them.

**MyCode** it will work fine

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class MyTest{
public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 int option = 0;
    do{
  String menu = "\n Please select an option to perform"
    + "\n1 (1) Get all uppercase letters."
    + "\n2 (2) Get every second letter."
    + "\n3 (3) Replace vowels with _ "
    + "\n4 (4) Get a count of all vowels."
    + "\n5 (5) Get position of all vowels."
    + "\n0 (0) To Exit.";
 System.out.println(menu);

option = in.nextInt();



if (option == 1){
System.out.println("1");
}

else if (option == 2){
System.out.println("2");
}

else if(option == 0){
System.out.println("0");
    break;
}else{
    System.out.println("\n\nWrong Choice\n\n");
}

}while(option != 0);

}
}
```

To clarify the difference here is the Code proposed by **Other users** which will result into an infinite loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class MyTest2{
public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 int option = 1;
    do{



if (option == 1){
System.out.println("1");
}

else if (option == 2){
System.out.println("2");
}

else if(option == 0){
System.out.println("0");
    break;
}else{
    System.out.println("\n\nWrong Choice\n\n");


  String menu = "\n Please select an option to perform"
    + "\n1 (1) Get all uppercase letters."
    + "\n2 (2) Get every second letter."
    + "\n3 (3) Replace vowels with _ "
    + "\n4 (4) Get a count of all vowels."
    + "\n5 (5) Get position of all vowels."
    + "\n0 (0) To Exit.";
 System.out.println(menu);

option = in.nextInt();



}

}while(option != 0);

}
}
```

Comment: just could you tell me what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: @KickButtowski If you are asking me because you got -1, then please let me tell you I didn't down vote your answer. But to tell you "wrong with your answer" As OP wants to write a logic for loop, so we need to ask in each iteration regarding the choice of user, but your lofic will only ask for the choice if user enter anything apart from 1 & 2, it will not ask user to enter choice if he enters 1 or 2. I hope you got what I am trying to say.

Comment: @KickButtowski Dear Friend, The loop will become an infinite loop in case of valid option, if user doesn't change the condition, as it is while loop, so same thing will be performed again and again until you change the condition. Try to run the code, you will find the difference.

Comment: This seemed to work the way I want it to, but for some reason it will not display anything with methods 3-5. But I know the methods work right because I have run them without the loop.

Comment: @user3769297 I have not written anything for your method 3 & 4 I have mentioned only ... in that place. You can put more else if conditions according to your need. If it works the way you want it to be. Then you should accept the answer to let others know about it.

Comment: I know, I just meant that when I added in the other options it wasn't working. It may have just been some simple typo on my part, but as I reviewed it it seemed correct. I did manage to get the program to work properly using a different answer which I selected.

Comment: @user3769297 Sure. That's good. But that logic has unnecessary two loops. There is no point of having two loops in this logic. Your work is done but the quality of logic is....... Do not write such logics in any exam or interview or while working on any project.